# Name of temporary File in Java change automatically

Tags: java, file

Here is my code

```
File outFile = null;
System.out.println("###DEB name = " + name);
System.out.println("###DEB extension = " + rozszezenie);
System.out.println("###DEB dir = " + dir);
if(name.length() < 3)
     name = FILE_NAME_PREFIX;
outFile = File.createTempFile(name+"_", "." + rozszezenie, dir);
System.out.println("###DEB outFile = " + outFile.getName());
```

after running it gives output:

```
###DEB name = BRAK;20160205;1016;501200911;tczelu
###DEB extension = ogg
###DEB dir = /tmp/tower_wind_tmp
###DEB outFile = BRAK;20160205;1016;501200911;tczelu_2859671049642865591.ogg
```

Where does these numbers (2859671049642865591) come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [`createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) (emphasis mine):

> Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings **to generate its name**.

This means that this method will generate a name and you can't supply your own name.

If you want to create a file with your own name then you probably don't want to create a *temporary* file. Instead, you should just create a new file with [`Files.createFile(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) from [Java NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), or [`File#createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.createTempFile(name+"_", "." + rozszezenie, dir);
```

create a new temporary file with a random name. Just use

```
new File(dir, name)
```

to create a File with the exact name you provide.

Comment: `new File(...)` doesn't create the file on disk.

Comment: So? you can then write to it if you so wish.

Comment: So the question is about creating a file. Which this answer doesn't do. It allocates a new `File` object, which is different.

Comment: Yes, I know what you're saying, but still, the question's code is asking why the getName() of the file is not what was passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I checked `public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)` and it use `static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir)` where inside this method is

```
long n = random.nextLong();
if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
    n = 0;      // corner case
} else {
    n = Math.abs(n);
}
```

that's from this number come from